# Barcode Generator for PHP 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to develop a barcode generator in my laravel app and I was looking for a plugin or a package that I can use, but all the packages I found requires PHP version 7 while I am already in PHP version 8. Are there any packages available on this already?

I want to keep my PHP version but if there is no solution to this then I would probably downgrade my PHP version.

Comment: I don't see why these wouldn't work so give it a go. The packages should update if there are any incompatabilities.

Comment: You're developing a barcode generator and you want to install a barcode generator plugin? :) Anyway code in PHP7 must be either compatible with  PHP 8 or it should be quite easy to make it compatible. You can fork any plugin you need and update it yourself.

Comment: what is the error you got when you trying to install the other packages?

Comment: https://github.com/milon/barcode   This package is compatible with Laravel 4.* , 5.*, 6.*, 7.* and 8.*

Comment: Problem 1
    - milon/barcode 8.0.0 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.0.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - milon/barcode 8.0.1 requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.        
    - Root composer.json requires milon/barcode ^8.0 -> satisfiable by milon/barcode[8.0.0, 8.0.1].

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._ - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

Try using:
[Simple QrCode](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode)

**Requires:**

- `php: >=7.2|^8.0`
- `ext-gd: *`

**Installation:**

`composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode`

**Usage:**

*A. GENERATING/SAVING TO A FILE*

```php
use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode;


QrCode::format("svg")
            ->size(50)
            ->generate("/* STRING HERE AS THE QR CODE CONTENT */", "/* FILE SYSTEM DESTINATION PATH */");
```

*B. GENERATING QR CODE IN BLADE TEMPLATES*

```php
<img alt="{{__('QR Code')}}" src="data:image/svg;base64,
                    {!! base64_encode(
\SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode::format('svg')->size(50)->generate('/* STRING HERE AS THE QR CODE CONTENT */')
                    ) !!}">
```

**Documentation:**

[Official Documentation](https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode)